# How can I take a pdf, and convert any jpeg2000/jpx/jp2 images in it to jpeg images?

Tags: macos, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am using MacOS Mojave on a Mac Mini, and I am also using an old Kindle Dx which cannot read jpeg2000 images. It also has trouble with too many or too large jpeg images.

I cannot use touchscreens, so newer e-readers and tablets aren't a solution.

So far, I've found some buggy solutions--

I can use Willus's k2pdfopt with -mode copy and -dev dx, which rasterizes everything. It's a good solution for scanned pdfs. If more detail is needed, -mode copy without -dev dx will preserve higher resolution. It's something of a last resort for pdf-born-pdfs, since text can be uglier and harder to read, and file sizes can increase alarmingly.

I can also use Ghostscript with -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4, which doesn't rasterize everything. It converts jpeg2000 images to jpeg images. But it doesn't tackle some oversized or poorly-constructed images, it often creates dark rectangles which can obscure text, and it occasionally loses the ability to search or select text. [P.S. I mean it takes a pdf which had searchable pdf and outputs one which does not. Also if I do any kind of image downsampling or removal, it sometimes rescales everything or loses pages.]

I have experimented with options to compress images in Ghostscript, with mixed success, and with the above bugs persisting. [P.S. I think I was downsampling, yes.]

For whatever reason, MacOS Quartz filters only work if they will reduce image sizes. So they tend not to work on the buggy images.

Now my ideal solution would preserve the text itself, preferably untangling ligatures, and would compress the images like Willus's k2pdfopt. But I have no idea if that's possible or how.

Short of that-- I'm wondering if there's a way to use Ghostscript to convert the jpeg2000 images without causing the gray rectangles or losing the ability to search or select text.

or if there's a way to use Quartz filters so they work. In some older versions of MacOS they did work.

or if there's a way to batch-print these pdf files to the appropriate resolution, apparently 800x1180, reprocessing images in the process.

I don't have much programming experience. I mainly use homebrew to install command-line tools, very sloppy bash scripts, and Automator to run them.

P.S. For a minimal example of the gray rectangles in Ghostscript, using the free pdf from here: https://www.peginc.com/store/test-drive-savage-worlds-the-wild-hunt/

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -o out.pdf in.pdf

substituting that pdf for in.pdf.

For a minimal example of losing searchable text, using the free pdf from here: http://datafortress2020.com/fileproject/details.php?image_id=498

same minimal script

Compatibility Level

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o out.pdf in.pdf

Aggressive Downsampling and Grayscale

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4
-g800x1080 -r150 -dPDFFitPage \
    -dFastWebView -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
    -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dColorImageResolution=75 -dGrayImageResolution=75 -dMonoImageResolution=150 -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \ -o out.pdf in.pdf

P.P.S. I can use k2pdfopt to rasterize to fit my Kindle. If the file has searchable text, this retains it, if it doesn't I can run tesseract in k2 or run ocrmypdf afterwards.

But if I want especially good graphics, or especially clear text, and the file has hundreds of pages, it will need hundreds of megs. I had blamed this on rasterizing the text, which was why my ideal solution was to keep text and rasterize images, but apparently it's an issue with the images themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you've found a bug, then it's helpful to report it. If you don't it will never be fixed. You can report a bug at https://bugs.ghostscript.com, please be sure to attach an example file to reproduce the problem and state the command line used.

The Ghostscript pdfwrite device does not, ever, produce JPEG2000 images (due to patent issues). So you don't need to set the CompatibilityLEvel at all, and I'd recommend that you do not. By setting the CompatibilityLevel you are limiting the output. Unless your device cannot handle later versions then don't do this.

Without seeing an example file, a command line and knowing the version and operating system it's obviously not possible for anyone to comment on your 'gray rectangles'.

You can reduce the size of images (in bytes) by downsampling (as opposed to compressing) them, you can't do anything about the number of images.

Note that searchable text depends on the construction of the PDF file, and so cannot ever be guaranteed. Searchable text (in the sense of ToUnicode CMaps) was a later addition to the PDF Reference and is always optional, because it's possible to have input from which the Unicode code points cannot be determined (without using OCR software) but a perfectly readable PDF file can still be produced.

Ghostscript itself can produce a PDF file which is a rendered representation of the original, wrapped up as a PDF. See the pdfimage* devices.

Tesseract can take images and produce PDF files with searchable text, produced by OCR'ing the images. This would seem to me to be your best option, though obviously I don't know if a single large image is going to be acceptable to your device.

### Edit

I already agreed that searching text is inherently not supported in PDF, except as an optional adjunct. The bug report you pointed to talks about 'corrupting text layers'. There are no text layers in PDF, and the text is neither corrupted nor missing, ts just not encoded as ASCII any more.

The reason you shouldn't set the resolution, and the size in pixels, is because PDF is not an image format. You aren't gaining anything by doing this. All that happens is that pdfwrite divides the 'g' valuess by the resolution, to get a media size in inches, and writes that as the MediaBox. Simpler just to set the Media Size. If you set the resolution you are fixing anything which **does** get rendered at that resolution. Choose a low resolution and you get crappy output. If you use a higher resolution then the image can be downscaled and smoothed giving better output.

It is indeed possible that your Kindle cannot handle transparency any better than the Mac, it is after all an old device. It's also possible that whoever built Ghostscript for you introduced a bug. I'm afraid we can't help you with either of those.

I did suggest, right back at the end of the original post, that you render the content to an image (Ghostscript will do that for you), then use Tesseract to convert the image back to a PDF, and at the same time OCR the text.

That will get past your problems with JPEG2000, will do a **better* job of creating searchable text, since even files that aren't already searchable will become so, and will allow you to specify the resolution.

Comment: I've tried to report most of these bugs, but been rebuffed because (a) the pdfs were malformed to begin with, and (b) removing the searchable text is not considered a bug. Now because this site doesn't support paragraphs in replies, I can't send example scripts.

Comment: Well if the PDF files are broken, then whatever happens if you try to modify them is sheer luck, and I did mention that being able to search text is a bonus. What bug numbers were declined ? I don't know what you mean by 'paragraphs in replies', its perfectly possible to put a paragraph in a Bugzilla thread. Also, I don't think scripts are a good idea, because then the developer has to use the same OS as you are in order to use the script. What's wrong with just quoting the command line ?

Comment: I notice the command line you are using above is a **great** deal more extensive than you originally indicated. Not only htat buyt much of it is either not a good idea or redundant. I wouldn't use FastWebView, it just makes the file pointlessly bigger. You shouldn't set the resolution, unless you are expecting content to be rendered, and liekwise you definitely should **not** set the media size in pixels!

Comment: A much simpler gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf input.pdf produces a PDF file which is 30% smaller, does not have gray rectangles in it (though you haven't said which of the 16 pages is affected for you) and doesn't contain any JPX images, which is what your question was all about I thought. That's for the Wild Hunt file.

Comment: This : -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dColorImageResolution=75 -dGrayImageResolution=75 -dMonoImageResolution=150 -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0  -o out.pdf SWTestDriveTheWildHunt.pdf also works for me, produces a still smaller file and also does not have any gray rectangles.

Comment: Here's one: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=702252

Comment: "You shouldn't set the resolution, unless you are expecting content to be rendered, and liekwise you definitely should not set the media size in pixels!" Why not? If the file size in pixels matches the device size in pixels, then the images are relatively clear. That's one reason Willus's k2pdfopt gets reasonably clear results with reasonably well-scanned pdfs. If they don't match, either the images are jagged, or they are oversized and slow to load.

Comment: I get the same rectangles on the cover and most other pages, with and without -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH, so it sounds like ghostscript has very different results on your machine. I have gs 9.52 installed through brew on MacOS 10.14.6.

Comment: This suggests a MacOS and iOS bug: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696331 But the same rectangles occur, and can obscure text, on the Kindle as well as the Mac.